# Trying to replace only the first occurrence of a string produces an error

Tags: php, str-replace

PHP7

Code:

```
$slug = '1196';
$id = '1';
str_replace($id, '', $slug, 1);
```

My objective is to get the first instance of '1' replaced, but I am getting the following error message:

> Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference

The PHP manual says:

> str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] ) : mixed

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fourth parameters is a variable that will hold the count of replacements. It is not a limit for the number of replacements you want to occur.

> If passed, this will be set to the number of replacements performed.

The https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php has a `limit` parameter. e.g.

```
$slug = '1196';
$id = '1';
echo preg_replace('/' . $id . '/', '', $slug, 1);
```

https://3v4l.org/VrTcg